# How to find all immediately adjacent siblings with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find all the immediately adjacent siblings of a node using a single XPath expression, if at all possible. Given the input

```xml
<a id="1"/>
<start/>
<a id="2"/>
<a id="3"/>
<b/>
<a id="4"/>
```

and an XPath expression similar to `//start/following-sibling::a`, I want to select **a[2]**, and **a[3]**, but not **a[4]**. Also, if there are any intervening elements between **start** and **a[2]**, nothing should be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest one I can find was this:

```
//start/following-sibling::a intersect //start/following-sibling::*[name()!='a'][1]/preceding-sibling::a
```

What this does is:

1. Take all the `a` siblings following `start`: `//start/following-sibling::a`. (Result: a2, a3, a4.) Set this to one side for now.
2. Then take the first non-a sibling following `start`: `//start/following-sibling::*[name()!='a'][1]` (Result: b.)
3. And find all the `a` nodes that precede it: `/preceding-sibling::a`. (Result: a1, a2, a3)
4. Take the intersection of 1 and 3. (Result: a2, a3)

**Update:** Another way to phrase it is `//start/following-sibling::*[name()!='a'][1]/preceding-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::start]`, this roughly translates to: take the first non-a sibling following `start`, count backwards but only choose elements that are still preceded by `start`.

**Update 2:** If you know that `b` will always be called `b`, you can of course replace the rather hard to read `following-sibling::*[name()!='a'][1]` part with `following-sibling::b[1]`.

Comment: Thank you! The method in your **Update** works perfectly. Must work on my XPath skills ...

Comment: Keep in mind that the first solution will need to be supplemented to account for the case where the `start` node is followed by nothing but `a` nodes. In that case, the second set in the intersection will be empty and thus the entire intersection will be empty.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with XPath 1.0; the ``intersect`` operator doesn't exist in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Following a solution that works with XPath 1.0:

```
//start[following-sibling::*[1][name() = 'a']]/following-sibling::a[last() = count(preceding-sibling::*[name() != 'a'][1]/following-sibling::a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

no way to test it, but `//start/following-sibling::*[1][self::a]` should return the immediate following sibling but only if it's "a"

Comment: This is good but as you say it only returns the first `a`. The requirement is to return all the `a`s that follow up to the point where a different tag is encountered.

Comment: yeah - I think your intersection will be better :)